# NaiveScript: how to use builder module with xml file, not a template string

Tags: nativescript

I have a xml template file. I need to "turn" it into code. Add some properties and then add to a parent container programatically.

XML template (it's much more complicated in the real app, this is just for example):

```
<StackLayout id="{{ 'recipe_' + recipe_id }}">
   <Label text="{{ title }}"/>
   <Label text="{{ description }}"/>
   <Button text="Choose" onTap="onRecipeBtnTap"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Code:

```
let recipeCard = builder.parse("~/templates/recipe.xml") //<-- problem here
let slide = new slide.Slide()
slide.addChild(recipeCard)
slidesContainer.add(slide)
```

The problem is that the builder module require xml string not a path. So, I fist need somehow to convert xml file to string. Please advise what is the best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found how to do that. Need to use the file-system module:

```
let template = fs.File.fromPath(__dirname + '/templates/recipe.xml')
let templateString = template.readTextSync()
let recipeCard = builder.parse(templateString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `"ui/builder"` and simply call its `load()` method and pass the path and name of the XML you want to load. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-fresco/blob/master/demo/app/pages/main-page.ts) example that showcases loading of XML with its own code behind (ts/js). For more information you can refer the [documentation](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#custom-components) about `"ui/builder"`.